# Trouble with JSON returned from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I've built a page (in WordPress) that is supposed to submit a form via AJAX, but whenever the form is submitted, the url changes to the form handler's url, and it just displays the JSON its supposed to return instead of using it to update the current page. It just looks like a blank page with:

```
{"id":"1","task":"test","status":"complete"}
```

Here's what I'm using for the form:

```
<div id='test'>
<form action ='handler.php' method='post' class='test_form complete'>
... hidden input fields ... 
<input type="submit" name="markcomplete" value="Mark Complete" /></form>
</div>
```

Here's the ajax that is submitting the form:

```
jQuery('.test_form').on('submit', function(e) {
   jQuery(this).hide();
   jQuery.ajax({
        url : myAjax.ajaxurl, //this is required for using ajax in WordPress
        dataType : "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {                   
          otherform = "#" + response.task + " form" + "." + response.status;
          jQuery(query).show();
          jQuery('#message').html("<p>status changed</p>");
    }
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

What this is supposed to do is hide the current form, show another form, and display a simple message that the status has been changed.

and here's the handler.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['markcomplete'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $task = $_POST['task'];
    $cparray = array('userid' => $id, 'task' => $task, 'satus' => "complete");
// function that makes changes to database...
wp_send_json($cparray); // this is the equivalent of echo json_encode($cparray);
}
```

I know the post is being sent, because I'm seeing the changes made to the database, and its displaying the JSON I want the current page to use. I'm pretty inexperienced with AJAX so I wouldn't be surprised if its something simple.

**Edit1**: JQuery is included in the project. I don't get any javascript errors, but on further inspection I see this message in the console when I click submit:

"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "handler.php".

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: what if you add `return false;` after `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: adding return false didn't change anything.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then it is probably due to a JS error that prevented code from finishing and thus continue the submit process: try to remove the Ajax call and keep the prevent and you will see that it won't load. So what you need to do is to use the browser debugger with breakpoint to prevent the page from loading and thus see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='test'>
  <form action="" method="POST" id="testForm" class='test_form complete'>
... hidden input fields ... 
  <input type="submit" name="markcomplete" value="Mark Complete" .></form>
   </div>


jQuery('#testForm').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
jQuery(this).hide();
jQuery.ajax({
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl, //this is required for using ajax in WordPress
    dataType : "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
    success: function (response) {                   
      otherform = "#" + response.task + " form" + "." + response.status;
      jQuery(query).show();
      jQuery('#message').html("<p>status changed</p>");
}
});

});
```

Use `e.preventDefault()` first to avoid form submission.

Comment: moving preventDefault() didn't help, still displays it the same way.

Comment: Check now! Do a bit of changing then tell

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue was I didn't put the jquery inside

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
```